# Bug - Personal Finance and Money Q&A - Windows 7 Fails to Render But Windows XP Does?

Tags: support, status-norepro, windows-7

[My question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/repeat-job-advertisements-do-i-smell-a-large-turn-over-rate-closed) on the Personal Finance and Money Q&A site doesn't render on my Windows 7 machines, but it does on my old Windows XP PC.  From outside my personal LAN, I've been able to access the post with Windows XP machines; I haven't been able to test it on any other Windows 7 boxes outside of my house.  I've tried Firefox 3.6/4.0, Chrome 10.0.648.204, Opera 11.01, IE8 and Safari 5.0.3 on the Windows 7 install and *NONE* of these browsers were able to render.

Here are 4 characteristics that I've been able to identify:

1. Blank white page; nothing renders at all
2. Can't view source (in any of the browsers on Windows 7 - can force it by using Firebug in Firefox, Developer Tools/JavaScript Console in Chrome, and Developer Tools in IE8)
3. Page Title when accessing from Google is

   ```
   search (GIF Image, 1x1 pixels)
   ```
4. Page Title when accessing from within StackExchange is

   ```
   repeat-job-advertisements-do-i-smell-a-large-turn-over-rate-closed (GIF Image, 1x1 pixels)
   ```

If you want the source results from the Firebug console, let me know (not a whole lot to show really).

Interesting thing on Item #3: this is pretty inconsistent when accessing from a Google search.  Sometimes I'll get the Page Title as described by Item #4 when clicking the link in the Google search, other times I'll get the Title from Item #3; the only way to **consistently** get the Page Title from the 3rd Item is to use the "Cached" link on Google.  As stated above, I can consistently get the Title from Item #4 by navigating through StackExchange.

I've also done some of the more mundane troubleshooting tasks (resetting devices in LAN, clearing cache, etc); for more background on this, you can review the correspondence on [my Meta post](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279/are-questions-about-careers-off-topic).

If I can check the "problem" post from a Windows 7 PC outside of my place, I'll post an update.

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried Firefox 3.6/4.0, Chrome 10.0.648.204, Opera 11.01, IE8 and Safari 5.0.3 on the Windows 7 install and NONE of these browsers were able to render.

I suspect you have a proxy, firewall, or antivirus running in Windows 7 that is interfering with HTTP in some way.

We have no other reports of this problem.

Comment: That's peculiar; I'm running Kaspersky Internet Security 2010 on my XP machine and my Windows 7 machines, yet XP works fine.  Firewalls are set to default on all machines at my place.  That's not to say there isn't something wrong with the Firewall/AV on Win7, just that it's confusing that I can access all my other posts across StackExchange except for that single one.  I'll play around with KIS to see what happens.  Thanks for the quick follow up.